# MSIX Include Additional Required Files

Tags: winforms, libvlc, appx, msix, libvlcsharp

I have a simple WinForms app that I'm trying to package with MSIX. The app itself requires additional files that when I build the MSIX App Project doesn't copy/include.

Specifically this LIBVLC folder that gets included during the WinForms app build itself.

[image]

If I manually copy that folder over into the AppX build folder, everything works. Obviously I'm trying to automate including that folder.

Folder manually copied over in screenshot below:

[image]

How can I accomplish this? GitHub minimal repo:
https://github.com/aherrick/MSIXWinFormsLIBVLC

Comment: related https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/454

Comment: I see what you're saying, but please don't include dlls in your git repository. That's confusing for other people who might want to reproduce locally

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that this line is your issue : https://github.com/aherrick/MSIXWinFormsLIBVLC/blob/0e717828a16e796a7a27e415cf45d33a50327da9/MSIXWinFormsLIBVLC.AppPackage/MSIXWinFormsLIBVLC.AppPackage.wapproj#L80

The nuget package isn't really well understood by the build tools as those are native files that we collect "before build". It seems to cause issues when a project references a project that references the nuget package, and the usual workaround is to reference the nuget package directly in the topmost project.

Is it possible to reference a nuget package in a .wapproj ?

If it isn't, that's an issue for this repository https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-nuget/ . Contributions welcome